where to store the mp3 file , so , that can be used in react native track player and most importantly how to access it
I have tried several methods found on internet, but may be because i would be missing something, so i wasn't able to achieve that i wanted. Is there any config, that i need to add so to add that file in the app bundle and can we accessible.
here are some references that i tried:

In React Native how do you bundle a text file and read it's value at runtime?
React Native import audio file from android res (but i am using the react native track player).
https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/967

I stored that mp3 file in android/app/src/main/assets but in the url if i provide this or any path it isn't accessible even when used with the require also , but that too didn't worked for me.
let path;
    RNFS.readFileAssets('omchant.mp3', 'base64')
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(':the file found');
            // path = ;
        })
        .catch((er) => console.log('teh error in the file path ==>', er));
    await TrackPlayer.add([
        {
            id: 1,
            url: require("/android/app/src/main/assets/filename.mp3"),
            title: 'Fluidity',
            artist: 'tobylane',
        },
    ]);

but didn't goes as expected.

The location of the path doesn't matter; you can place it anywhere you prefer!
Just make sure to add the artwork, and it should work correctly.
await TrackPlayer.add([
        {
            id: 1,
            url: require("./filename.mp3"),
            title: 'Fluidity',
            artist: 'tobylane',
            artwork: require('./cover.jpg'),
        },
    ]);


I don't want any artwork to be displayed i just want to store a small mp3 which i am using in my app, so that i can use without internet and without downloading that song for the first time while installing, to my external storage.

Let's do a test whether music can play without artwork or not, For now add a demo artwork and test.
